Twisted Poincaré duality reduces to usual one when manifold is oriented
Theorem 12.15 of Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Bott and Tu states that when $M$ is a smooth of dimension $n$ and $\mathfrak U$ is a a good cover of $M$ satisfying the condition $(*)$, then we have an isomorphism
\begin{align}
H^*_c(M)\cong H_{n-*}(\mathfrak U,\mathscr H^n_c),
\end{align}
where the LHS is the de-Rham cohomology of $M$ with compact support, and the RHS is the Cech homology of of the cover $\mathfrak U$ with coefficients in the covariant functor
\begin{align}
\mathscr H^n_c(U)=H^n_c(U)
\end{align}
and the every inclussion is sent to extension by zero. I have been told that this is the twisted version of the "usual" Poincaré duality
\begin{align}
H^*_{dR}(M)\cong \bigr(H_c^{n-*}\bigr(M))^{\vee}.
\end{align}
How can we obtain the latter from the former in the oriented case?

This follows from three facts:

Ordinary cohomology of $M$ is the sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf on $M$. This can be taken as a definition, or is a theorem that needs to be proven.

This sheaf cohomology can be computed as Cech cohomology.

The sheaffification of $U\mapsto H^n_c(U)$ is the constant sheaf if and only if $M$ is orientable. To see this, prove it's locally constant (since $M$ is a manifold), then show that a global section exists (and thus the sheaf is constant) iff the manifold is orientable.


In general, this sheaf is called the orientation sheaf $\omega_M$ of $M$. This sheaf (and associated duality) shows up much more generally for singular spaces, this is Verdier duality. This requires the full power of derived categories to state properly though, as for a general space $X$, the dualising sheaf is a complex of sheaves $\omega_X$.

Thank you. The functor $U\mapsto H^n_c(U)$ however, is not a pre-sheaf, as it is covariant. This is like Cech homology of a covariant sheaf (?). Does the general theory of sheaves stay valid. Do you know if  there is a good reference where this is discussed?

Yep, my mistake, this thing is naturally a cosheaf, which I think is the correct way to think about this duality (but this uses infinity categories, see Lurie HTT). In this case, dualising this gives the presheaf you are after, which is the orientation sheaf. Unfortunately I don't know of a source in this generality, but the key thing is Verdier duality. In the generality of well behaved stratified spaces, Goresky and Macpherson's Intersection cohomology II gives a great overview.
